# UK: is it possible to buy Vanguard Growth Index Funds (VGIX)?

Tags: united-kingdom, index-fund, vanguard, growth

Is it possible to invest in the Vanguard growth index funds if you're based in the UK?

Either directly with Vanguard or via a broker.

I asked Charles Stanley but they don't do it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unless that fund is in the product range Vanguard choose market to UK investors (and it does not appear to be), no UK broker (or Vanguard themselves) will be able to offer it to you.  For regulatory reasons.

The world is not short of US large-cap growth funds; surely there are more accessible UK domiciled equivalents?